# Rails tag helper is not displaying as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper, ruby-on-rails-5.2

```
def amount_html
  h.tag.span do
    h.tag.del do
      'value1'
    end
    'value2'
  end
end
```

I am getting:

```
<span> value2 </span>
```

Instead of:

```
<span><del>value1</dev> value2 </span>
```

Do I need to do a join or something? if so how?

Comment: updated question, value1 and value2 are strings

Answer (score 1):

Tags are just strings, you need to concatenate them. Also note that tags are escaped by default, so you do not need to call `h` on them.

```
def amount_html
  tag.span do
    tag.del do
      'value1'
    end + 
    'value2'
  end
end
```

Or as @mu pointed out, you can also use [`concat`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/concat), which adds each string to the output buffer without having to manually `+` them together:

```
tag.span do
  concat tag.del('value1')
  concat 'value2'
end
```

Comment: Or use `concat`: `concat tag.del('value1')` and `concat 'value2'.

Comment: I get undefined method `concat' when I try it